# Finding a basis in a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble with the Hilbert spaces.

I have a Hilbert space span by the set
$$\{1, \sin(x), \cos(x), \sin^2(x), \cos^2(x), \sin(2x), \cos(2x)\}$$

Now I'm trying to find a basis and the dimension of this space. To find the dimension I have first to find a basis, right?

So for a basis: am I just looking for the functions that can build up any function by addition or multiplication with a constant?

Thank you in advance! 
-Alex

Comment: Your Hilbert space is spanned by your functions, hence its dimension is at most the number of functions that you have. Now some of your functions are linear combinations of others, so you need to remove them - they don't add anything new to your space.

Comment: Thank you! So I guess I have to remove the 1 as it is a combination of ${sin}^2(x)$ + ${cos}^2(x)$, but all other functions still should remain?

Comment: Yes, you can remove either $1$ or $\cos^2x$, or $\sin^2x$ - this would not affect the spanned space. However, there remain other function(s) that you can get rid of.

Comment: Yes, just got it :-) So I can also remove cos(2x) as it can be written as ${cos}^2(x) - {sin}^2(x)$. But I guess that should be all then?

Comment: Now, in order to convert your guess into a rigorous statement, you need to prove that the remaining functions are linearly independent. You can do that by definition, for example.

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: How do you prove that a certain family functions is a basis of the vector space, spanned by these functions?